# discord.py @silent message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a small discord bot and want to create a `!luck` command. If you use it the result should be like `@wumpus won!`. Now, to prevent ping spam there's a possibility to "turn off" pings, just add @silence to your message. Basically it works perfectly, when I add @silent before my message, the user doesn't gets pinged (message looks like this after sending: `@wumpus this is a silent mention`). But if I want to do that with my discord bot, the `@silent` before the message is just like normel text.

My code:

```py
await ctx.message.reply(f"@silent <@{choice(members)}> won!")
```

The result is `@silent @wumpus won!`

How can I use the `@silent` feature in discord.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new "silent" Parameter for that. It came with the discord.py 2.2 update. Make sure to update your discord.py for it to work.

```
await ctx.message.reply(f"{ctx.message.author.mention} won!", silent=True)
```

It should show like this:

[image: silent message example]